# Cocos2d: Lock CCSprite position after dragging it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I I'm working on a game in Cocos2D and I have a CCSprite Subclass with CCTargetedTouchDelegate wich is implemented so I can drag the sprite around on screen. I want the sprite to lock in it's position once the user's finger leaves the screen. Is there any way I can do this?? In the ccTouchEnded method I'd guess? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `bool lock` variable to your class fields. Make it `false` in your `init` method.
In touchBegan and touchMoved methods check `if (!lock) {your code }`. In touchEnded make it `true`.

Comment: Hi, thank you! worked out great...In touchEnded you have to change the  bool lock variable to true though! Thank you very much...helped me a lot ;) alex